# mysql can't drop corrupt innodb table

Tags: mysql, innodb, disaster-recovery

So I'm dealing with a MySQL server which ran out of disk space and has mostly InnoDB tables which of course got corrupted. I'm trying to drop and recreate the damaged tables but MySQL won't let me do anything with them, including repair. As you can see, this is no end of fun. It should be noted that only this one table seems to cause any of these errors.

```
mysql> drop table myschema.mytable;
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query

mysql> repair table myschema.mytable;
#results in the following
| myschema.mytable | repair | Error    | Out of memory; restart server and try again (needed 2 bytes)               |
| myschema.mytable | repair | Error    | Incorrect information in file: './myschema/mytable.frm' |
| myschema.mytable | repair | error    | Corrupt 

mysql> describe myschema.mytable; 
ERROR 1037 (HY001): Out of memory; restart server and try again (needed 2 bytes)
```

If I stop the server and move the table's .frm and ibd files out of the way, then restart, I can't recreate it, because the server says it already exists (even though it can't be seen in INFORMATION_SCHEMA). In this state I can't drop it either because the server says it isn't there.

I've looked high and low for answers but at this point, but I'm no DBA so I'm lost. I can't figure out how to fix this table, and I can't figure out how to get rid of it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you can also try at http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi @ben Hardy, If my reply has answered your question could you please approve it and upvote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether my answer at this point would be useful for you or not but I suppose it would help others.

This is not very uncommon issue. The reason for this corruption could be varied but the fix is simple though.

`You have to dump your table and recreate it again.`

We can achieve this by setting `innodb_force_recovery=1` parameter in the my.cnf file and then restart mysql.

Please read this link for more information about this parameter. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html

Once your problem is fixed you can remove the parameter.

Cheers!

Comment: I don't know if you tried this yourself or that you just copied the directions from the mysql site. The problem is that MySQL CANNOT even remove, let alone recover the the table because it is corrupted beyond repair. IMHO I think it is a design flaw that a corrupted table can prevent the database to be removed. The only solution is to completely re-create the MySQL server from scratch and import database backups.